# Android - failed to connect to settings.crashlytics.com/54.83.49.38 (port 443) after 10000ms

Tags: java, android, sdk, crashlytics

I am using fabric.io SDK in my Android App app.

it's not working. having this error message in Android Studio Logcat:

```
E/Fabric﹕ Unknown error while loading Crashlytics settings. Crashes will be cached until settings can be retrieved.
    io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest$HttpRequestException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to settings.crashlytics.com/54.83.49.38 (port 443) after 10000ms
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.code(HttpRequest.java:1409)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.handleResponse(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:96)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.invoke(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:83)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsController.loadSettingsData(DefaultSettingsController.java:80)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsController.loadSettingsData(DefaultSettingsController.java:64)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.Settings.loadSettingsData(Settings.java:156)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.retrieveSettingsData(Onboarding.java:123)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:99)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:45)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:63)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:28)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:311)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to settings.crashlytics.com/54.83.49.38 (port 443) after 10000ms
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:169)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:139)
            at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:1194)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:392)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:295)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:491)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.code(HttpRequest.java:1407)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.handleResponse(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:96)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.invoke(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:83)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsController.loadSettingsData(DefaultSettingsController.java:80)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsController.loadSettingsData(DefaultSettingsController.java:64)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.Settings.loadSettingsData(Settings.java:156)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.retrieveSettingsData(Onboarding.java:123)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:99)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:45)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:63)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:28)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:311)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
08-28 16:42:29.665  22669-22710/com.my.app W/Fabric﹕ Received null settings, skipping initialization!
08-28 16:42:29.665  22669-22705/com.my.app E/Answers﹕ Failed to retrieve settings
```

Here is my application Class:

```
...
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //Initiate SDKs
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());   //Crashlytics
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);        //Facebook
        registerParse();                        //Parse
...
```

Answer (score 10):

Basically the connection does not work...

**Resons might be:**

1. Usual connections problems
2. Other software which blocks (Adblockers) / (check that first, common problem)
3. Proxies or some specific port settings
4. Possibly there are many others...

It's hard to say what might be the reason in this case. I would try different conditions.

Comment: I found that it was due to my Android device not having a network connection. Go figure

Comment: @HaydenKai, You just saved me from pulling my hair out. Thanks.

Comment: well after two years this issue persists .. i am using 4g intenert connection and its working

Answer (score 2):

Check the changes in the `fabric.properties` and try to reset your `apiSecret` to the original.

It helped me in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the home network ad-blocker was blocking the request.

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?